# Substitution method for integration.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been taught that substitution is essentially the "reverse" of differentiation. We are essentially manipulating the function  as such to achieve something of the form $f(g(x))g'(x)dx$. For example when we integrate the function $(3x+1)^4$. We manipulate it so that $\frac{1}{3}\int (3x+1)^5(3) \, dx$. This is the form we want, so we continue the u substitution.

However there is another rule that is expressed as the following

[image]

I've been taught that this is a simplification of integration by substitution. However, I do not understand. How is this and integration by substitution related?

Furthermore, when does integration by substiution not work. For some reason I cannot do the following integral $\int (3x^2+1)^5 \, dx$ using u substituion. Why not?

Comment: "*scalars do not posses direction*" $\;-\;$ Scalars do possess a sign (assuming *real* scalars). Same as why multiplying a positive number by $\,-1\,$ results in a negative number.

Comment: If you think of the real number line as a 1D space, real scalars do possess direction - the positive or negative direction (i.e., the sign of a number).

Answer (score 1):

Why does substitution not work on $\int (3x^2+1)^5 \, dx$ ?

For your displayed formula, when we substitute $u=ax+b$ we have $du = a \,dx$ where $a$ is constant, so we can factor it outside the integral.

But for $\int (3x^2+1)^5 \, dx$, if we try substitution $u=3x^2+1$ we get $du = 6x\,dx$, where $6x$ is not constant, so we cannot factor it out:
$$
\int(3x^2+1)^5\;dx = \int u^5 \frac{du}{6x} = \int\frac{u^5}{6\sqrt{\frac{u-1}{3}}}\,du
$$
Not very helpful.